# UnsatisfiedDependencyException for org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.GraphQlTester

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-graphql

Getting below exception when I am executing the testcase given in below code for spring boot weblfux project using spring-graphql :-

Please let me know what is the issue. This project is using spring boot webflux and spring graphql.

Error :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cg.bms.QueryTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'graphQlTester': No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.GraphQlTester' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Testcase :-

```
     @GraphQlTest(PostGraphQLController.class)
     class QueryTests {
     @Autowired
     GraphQlTester graphQlTester;
     @MockBean
     PostServiceImpl postService;
         @Test
         void getAllPosts(){
         when(postService.getAllPosts()).thenReturn(Flux.just(
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your project with the "DEBUG=true" environment variable or add the "debug: true" configuration property in your `application.yml` file. This should get the auto-configuration report from Spring Boot on the console (see [this section in the Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.startup-failure)).

There, you should see why the `GraphQlAutoConfiguration` or the `GraphQlTesterAutoConfiguration` do not match. I suspect that it's not finding the graphql schema in the `classpath:graphql/` location because you might have a similar location that shadows it in `src/test/resources`. The [location of graphql test queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/reference/testing.html#testing.requests) should be `src/test/resources/graphql-test/`.